# How to filter out pairs of rows within groups Snowflake

Tags: filter, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partitioning

I have a table A that is like:

| ID | PET | COUNTRY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | DOG | US |
| 72 | DOG | CA |
| 15 | CAT | CA |
| 36 | CAT | US |
| 21 | SNAKE | FR |
| 12 | SNAKE | IN |
| 20 | PIG | US |
| 14 | PIG | RS |
| 33 | HORSE | IQ |
| 90 | HORSE | ID |

The rows are paired/grouped based on matching PET. I would like to only select the pairs that include the US in the country. Basically each pair for the country value would have the US and another country/one of the values has to be the US. So for example, the resulting table would be

| ID | PET | COUNTRY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | DOG | US |
| 72 | DOG | CA |
| 15 | CAT | CA |
| 36 | CAT | US |
| 20 | PIG | US |
| 14 | PIG | RS |

Would this be achieved by a partition of some sort? I am not sure how to case the select statement within a grouping... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just join based on PET, first filtering out for `country = US`.

```
with data_cte (ID,PET,COUNTRY) as (
select * from values 
(45,'DOG','US'),
(72,'DOG','CA'),
(15,'CAT','CA'),
(36,'CAT','US'),
(21,'SNAKE','FR'),
(12,'SNAKE','IN'),
(20,'PIG','US'),
(14,'PIG','RS'),
(33,'HORSE','IQ'),
(90,'HORSE','ID')
), cte_1 as(
select * from data_cte
where country = 'US')
select d.* from data_cte d join
cte_1 c
where d.pet = c.pet;
```

Gives following result -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `QUALIFY` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY COUNT_IF(COUNTRY = 'US') OVER(PARTITION BY PET) > 0
   AND COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PET) > 1;
```

`COUNT_IF(COUNTRY = 'US') OVER(PARTITION BY PET) > 0` - at least one row in the group has to be US

`COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PET) > 1` - more than one row per pet

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(ID INT,PET TEXT,COUNTRY TEXT)
AS
SELECT * FROM VALUES (45,'DOG','US'),    (72,'DOG','CA'),
(15,'CAT','CA'),     (36,'CAT','US'),    (21,'SNAKE','FR'),
(12,'SNAKE','IN'),   (20,'PIG','US'),    (14,'PIG','RS'),
(33,'HORSE','IQ'),   (90,'HORSE','ID');
```

Output:

[image]